# How can I change the Login Screen Keyboard to Dvorak-fr

Tags: greeter

I would like to change the login screen keyboard to dvorak-fr but I can't find a way and the keyboard for login is in qwerty.

The keyboard indicator in Greeter say "No other layout available" and tty1 is in dvorak-fr as expected (as well as my session once I am logged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution works fine for me:

- First open `Language & region` and add required language and **layout**.
- Now open terminal and run:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
  ```

  Then it asks to select the following options:

  1. Keyboard model: Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  2. Country of origin for the keyboard: Select  **French** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

     [image: Imgur]
  3. Keyboard layout: Select **French - French (dvorak)** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

     [image: Imgur]

  From now press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> and continue for remaining options till end.
- Now **reboot** the system.

Comment: If you have a mac, still press enter for the keyboard. It's doesn't work if you choose macbook/macbook-pro.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved the problem for me.
Goto System Settings -> Language & Region

The window would probably say something like language not properly installed. CClick on it and let it install.
That's about it.

Comment: It didn't work for me but I think it's linked to a [bug of switchboard](https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-locale/+bug/1487767)